# How to handle this code in Many-One in linq

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-one

This code is a sample part of my data layer ...

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(DBHelper.GetConnectionString()))
        {
          var result = from item in db.GetTable<Table1>()
                       select new { item};

          foreach (var obj in result)
                   {
                    Table1 retVal = new Table1();
                    retVal = obj.item;
                     List<Table2> tbl2List = new Table2Data().SelectTable2(retVal.Table2ID);
                    foreach (Table2 tbl in tbl2List)
                        {
                            retVal.Table2 += tbl;
                        }
                    retValList.Add(retVal);
                    }
}
```

So, I have a DataContext block, I get table in this way

```
db.GetTable<Table1>()
```

Because of my specific architecture ...

in the first loop of foreach, I fill main object with this code:

```
Table1 retVal = new Table1();
                    retVal = obj.item;
```

so retVal is my return value ...

For my Many-One relation , in main loop , i connect db each time and fetch data to fill object ...

This code:

```
List<Table2> tbl2List = new Table2Data().SelectTable2(retVal.Table2ID);
                    foreach (Table2 tbl in tbl2List)
                        {
                            retVal.Table2 += tbl;
                        }
```

I know this is not good but this is my way ..

And now my main question is:

**How can I handle this Many-One relation ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly , i prefer to use EF instead of Linq-To-SQL ...

```
var result = from item in db.Table1
                           .Include(a=> a.Table2)
                   select new { item};
```

If you have question to do that, feel free